# How to access in-app purchase history in flutter?

Tags: flutter, in-app-purchase

I would like to implement in-app purchases in flutter using the [flutter_inapp_purchase](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_inapp_purchase) library.

Purchasing the item using `buyProduct()` already works, however I would like to ensure that customers who have already purchased an item are forwarded automatically and are not interrupted with the purchase dialog. This is why I request the purchase history of the customer with

```
List<PurchasedItem> purchaseHistory =
                      await FlutterInappPurchase.getPurchaseHistory();
```

However I have trouble working with the received `purchaseHistory` list, how do I now check whether the in-app purchase id of e.g. `'com.test.points100'` is contained in that list or not, i.e whether the user has already purchased the item wtih the id `'com.test.points100'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try

```
List<PurchasedItem> purchaseHistory =
                  await FlutterInappPurchase.getPurchaseHistory();
int purchaseIndex = purchaseHistory.indexWhere((item) =>
    item.productId == "com.test.points100"
);
bool hasPurchased = purchaseIndex >= 0;
```

Note I'm not familiar with this library - it may be that `getPurchaseHistory` returns cancelled or invalid purchases as well - better check that.

Comment: It worked! `getPurchaseHistory` only seems to include valid and successful purchases which should make it a good candidate for my case. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: not working in new version of in_app_purchase: ^3.1.7, Please provide a latest solution, im stuck to checking where user cancelled subscription or expired subscription

Comment: Could you please suggest a solution to connect in-app purchase. I an using flutter in-app-purchase but it doesn't listen the connectionUpdated event